# Scaling full screen video to maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-videoview

I'm working on an application that needs to display full screen video in the cleanest way possible. A well known example of this would be Snapchat. When viewing a snap, the video is full screen and maintains it's aspect ratio.

Currently, i'm using a custom `VideoView` set to `match_parent`. The code for the custom `VideoView` is below:

```
public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

    private int leftAdjustment;
    private int topAdjustment;

    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int videoWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int videoHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        int viewWidth = getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec);
        int viewHeight = getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (videoWidth == viewWidth) {
            int newWidth = (int) ((float) videoWidth / videoHeight * viewHeight);
            setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, viewHeight);
            leftAdjustment = -(newWidth - viewWidth) / 2;
        } else {
            int newHeight = (int) ((float) videoHeight / videoWidth * viewWidth);
            setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, newHeight);
            topAdjustment = -(newHeight - viewHeight) / 2;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.layout(l + leftAdjustment, t + topAdjustment, r + leftAdjustment, b + topAdjustment);
    }
}
```

While this does in fact maintain the aspect ratio of the video, most of the video is off screen.

A few questions:

1. How does Snapchat do this? Is it because every video is recorded inside the application, they already know the aspect ratio?
2. What is the best way to display the video full screen while maintain the aspect ratio?

Comment: were you able to solve it?